# How to Debug Facebook Messenger Extensions?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-messenger

I'm working on [Facebook Messenger Extensions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/chat-extensions) and want to know how to debug frontend (I'm using React). Actually, we don't have access to the console in the webview :(

Any advice ? Best Practices ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now open webviews in a Messenger chat on the Facebook webpage and debug in the console as normal. Make sure to use the updated [Messenger Extensions SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/getContext) getContext() function though.

Comment: Thanks ! I found this solution too :)

Comment: Could you explain this in a bit more details? How would you access the chat extensions on a webpage? and by webpage, you mean on a computer (as opposed to smart phone)? @jammygb